# Adjusting the size of the web on the flutter

Tags: flutter

Can you adjust the execution size of the Chrome browser on the flutter? I want to be able to adjust the size of my web program to smaller like a messenger program.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'basic',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
            width: 0.5625*360,
            height: 360,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to think about size because during the debug mode app size is always larger but when you make a release build it will decrease.